# How can I model condiment/sauce?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shape-keys

I want to model a condiment. It's call sambal. The red paste in the picture. It's a solid-liquid like sauce. How do I model this? A semisphere? Use a fluid modifier?

[image: sambal]

Comment: I tried to use a open bottom hemisphere + displace modifier (type: clouds, size 0.21). Thats the similar shape I can get

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something along these lines?

**Modelling**

[image]

- Create a blob mesh for the general area of your condiment. This is a UV sphere, pulled around with Proportional Edit, with its mesh *Header > Mesh > Transform > Randomize*d
- Make the blob an emitter of a particle system.. All on frame 1, no physics, aimed at a small Collection of onion-bits in the particle-system's 'Render' panel. Play with the rotations, scales, etc.

[image]

- Once you're happy with the surface features,'Convert' the particle system to real instances in the modifier stack, and apply the modifier.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> Join the ex-particles to the main mesh, and give it a *Remesh* modifier at a high enough resolution for your desired detail.
- Here, I've *Header> Mesh > Clean Up > Decimate*d the mesh.. and ..

[image]

.. given it 1 level of *Subdivision*. You could obviously try other things, here, smoothing, relaxing, etc. So long as you back up destructive steps, you can feel your way through.

**Shading**

[image]

- Here, in Cycles, using an 'Inside' *Ambient Occlusion* input producing a wide greyscale over the surface, put through two color-ramps.The aim is to pull the onion pieces back out for different treatment.
- The top mask is very hard, to control the base color of the material, keeping the orange to the onions.
- The bottom mask biases the noisy bump map to the smooth areas, avoiding the onions.
- The shader uses Subsurface Scattering, set to a low radius, to catch the onions more than the rest, and biased to yellow in the 'Radius': (0.6,0.6,0.2). Your settings will depend on the size of your model. (Recommend life-size)...

[image]

.. with a few extra chunks of onion added to cover up the bits of the surface you don't like :)

Comment: That's what you call _"Seasoned Advice"_

Comment: ..@batFINGER Cookin' on gas, today, Mr. FINGER.. :)